# SQL - Use maths operations in WHERE condition

Tags: php, sql

I currently have this PHP/SQL code :

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$sqlQuery = 'SELECT id FROM post 
            WHERE (100*((agree+disagree)-('.nbDays('date', $today).')*10) >= 75)';
```

And my nbDays function.

```
function nbDays($debut, $fin) {
    $nbSecondes= 60*60*24;

    $debut_ts = strtotime($debut);
    $fin_ts = strtotime($fin);
    $diff = $fin_ts - $debut_ts;
    return round($diff / $nbSecondes);
}
```

Here is what my post table looks like :

```
Post
-- #id
-- [int] agree
-- [int] disagree
-- [datetime] date
```

What i want to do is return an array of ids for the post that match this condition;

**(100 * ( agree/ (agree+disagree) )-(number of days from post date to today) ) > 75**

I want to use an SQL request so that I don't have to list all posts before sorting them out.

I hope I'm clear enough, and wish you could help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you really trying to call a php function in a query ?

Comment: you should consider using `DATEDIFF`, or the equivalent for your chosen DBMS

Comment: You're calling nbDays() with a value from the database (date) ___before___ before you've retrieved it from the database.... SQL don't work that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can write a database stored procedure to process
your logic . then call database procedure directly in php . In short
 if you used MYSQL maybe you can try following simple query.

```
SELECT id FROM post WHERE (100*((agree+disagree)-(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date))*10) >= 75);
```